# Array multidimensional no C# igual PHP?

Tags: php, c#, array, foreach, dicionário

Primeira vez aqui nesse fórum, geralmente uso stack overflow mas vamos lá.

Minha pergunta é referente a array no C#:
Sou mais familiarizado com PHP e no php podemos dar nome aos nossos índices da array por exemplo:

```
$array = ["nome"=>"Pedro", "Idade"=>18];
```

Minha dúvida é, é possível dar nome aos índices de um array no C#?

caso não, aproveitando o post, pergunta 2:
em uma array construída dessa forma:

```
string[,] array = new string[,]
{
   {"nome0", "idade1"},
   {"nome0", "idade1"}
};
```

Como eu faria em um foreach para pegar em cada passagem sempre o nome e a idade correspondente?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Se ainda não o fez, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Comment: "Primeira vez aqui nesse fórum, geralmente uso stack overflow mas vamos lá." Que site é esse? :)

Answer (score 6):

Vou mostrar várias formas de fazer tudo isso, essa passou raspando em ser mais de uma pergunta.

Começamos criando um dicionário que é o equivalente ao *array* associativo do PHP.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string> {["nome"] = "Pedro", ["Idade"] = "18"};
foreach (var item in dict) {
    WriteLine($"{item.Key} => {item.Value}");
}
```

Como C# é uma linguagem tipada é necessário indicar qual o tipo da chave e do valor. Por isso não pode misturar tipos como foi feito no exemplo do PHP. Tem uma maneira de resolver isso, mas não costuma ser adequado em C#. Basta usar o tipo `object` que aceita qualquer coisa. Com isso perde a segurança de tipos da linguagem. Assim:

```
var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, object> {["nome"] = "Pedro", ["Idade"] = 18};
foreach (var item in dict2) {
    WriteLine($"{item.Key} => {item.Value}");
}
```

Tem outras maneiras de obter um efeito semelhante, mas repito, melhor evitar.

Usando um *array* multidimensional pode iterar por todos os itens sem se preocupar com a dimensão. Lembrando que a tipagem conta aqui também, mas o exemplo da pergunta parece já considerar isso.

```
var array = new string[,] {
   {"nome0", "idade1"},
   {"nome1", "idade2"}
};
foreach (var item in array) {
    WriteLine($"{item}");
}
```

Mas se quiser varrer o *array* considerando as dimensões não pode usar `foreach`. Faça assim:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++) { //pega o tamanho da dimensão 0
    for (var j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++) { //pega o tamanho da dimensão 1
        WriteLine($"{array[i, j]}");
    }
}
```

Até é possível abstrair o acesso e usar o `foreach`. Para isso precisaria criar uma classe com um método iterador que retorne as dimensões de forma conveniente para usar no `foreach`. Não vou dar um exemplo porque acho que essa solução nem é a mais adequada.

Em C# quase sempre é mais interessante usar *jagged array* (*array* de *array*) do que um *array* multidimensional.

```
var jaggedArray = new string[2][] {new string[2] {"nome0", "idade1"}, new string[2] {"nome1", "idade2"}};
foreach (var subArray in jaggedArray) {
    foreach (var item in subArray) {
        WriteLine($"{item}");
    }
}
```

Mas parece que o que deseja mesmo é criar uma classe com um objeto específico e criar uma lista. Em PHP se usa *array* pra tudo. C# é mais otimizado e tem um mecanismo para cada necessidade. Pelo exemplo uma lista parece ser melhor que um *array*. E que a outra dimensão parece ser apenas uma forma diferente de usar o *array* associativo que é comum em PHP (ainda que a linguagem aceite classes também, mas que pela natureza dela não costuma ser usada para isso).

```
var listaPessoas = new List<Pessoa> {
    new Pessoa {Nome = "Pedro", Idade = 18},
    new Pessoa {Nome = "João", Idade = 15}
};
foreach (var item in listaPessoas) {
    WriteLine($"{item.Nome} => {item.Idade}");
}

public class Pessoa {
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Idade { get; set; }
}
```

Em alguns casos uma `struct` pode ser melhor que uma classe.

Na verdade seria possível usar uma tupla para evitar criar uma classe que nem sempre é desejável (não acho que seja o caso) que até versão 6 não era conveniente. [Em C# 7 é bem mais conveniente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195460/101) em alguns casos diferentes desse.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/DdDrk7). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F2JSZc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/MultiDimentional.cs).

Obviamente usei técnicas mais modernas em todo o código.

Documentações:

- [*Array*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)
- [*Array* multidimensional](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)
- [*Jagged Array*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)
- [Dicionário](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0)
- [Classe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)
- [`foreach`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/using-foreach-with-arrays?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)

Answer (score 1):

Olá, bom dia.

Para sua segunda pergunta, você pode fazer um foreach desta forma:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[,] array = new string[,]
       {
           {"nome0", "idade1"},
           {"nome1", "idade2"}
       };

        foreach (var item in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Para a primeira pergunta, eu não sei se eu entendi, mas se for uma lista com chave e valor, você poderia fazer assim:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> array = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        array.Add("nome", "Joao");
        array.Add("nome2", "Akame");

        foreach (var item in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Para saber mais sobre dictionary: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx