# Como acessar apenas a primeira posição de cada linha em um array de arrays (matriz / array multidimensional) utilizando foreach?

Tags: c#, array, loop, foreach, array-multidimensional

Eu tenho um *array* multidimensional / *array* de *arrays* / matriz (como preferir chamar):

```cs
    public string[,] operacoes = 
    { 
       { "SOMA", "", "" }, 
       { "SUBTRAÇÃO", "", "" }, 
       { "MULTIPLICAÇÃO", "", "" }, 
       { "DIVISÃO", "", "" } 
    };
```

Estou usando um loop foreach para retornar apenas a primeira posição de cada linha. As outras posições não são relevantes para esse caso.

```cs
foreach (string op in operacoes)
{
   ...
}
```

O que eu poderia fazer para retornar apenas essas posições com nomes de operações e ignorar o restante?

Comment: Usar um for normal.

Answer (score 4):

O `foreach` vai percorrer todos os elementos da coleção. Para fazer o que você precisa, é só usar um `for` normal.

Note que a propriedade `Length` vai retornar a quantidade **total** de elementos na coleção, ou seja, vai considerar todas as dimensões.

No seu caso, é necessário percorrer a dimensão zero e sempre mostrar o primeiro elemento dela.

```
void Main()
{
    string[,] operacoes = 
    { 
       { "SOMA", "", "" }, 
       { "SUBTRAÇÃO", "", "" }, 
       { "MULTIPLICAÇÃO", "", "" }, 
       { "DIVISÃO", "", "" } 
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < operacoes.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(operacoes[i, 0]);
    }
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no Repl.it**](https://repl.it/@jfbueno/ptso396160)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Você tem que pegar manualmente a primeira coluna e por isso não pode usar o `foreach`, para isso existe o `for`bruto e o o método [`GetLength()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getlength?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que dá o tamanho de uma dimensão, como você quer andar em cada linha, e é a dimensão 0.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        string[,] operacoes = { 
           { "SOMA", "x", "" },
           { "SUBTRAÇÃO", "x", "" },
           { "MULTIPLICAÇÃO", "x", "" },
           { "DIVISÃO", "x", "" }
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < operacoes.GetLength(0); i++) WriteLine(operacoes[i, 0]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/CCewXj). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dbCXVV). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/GetFisrtColumn.cs).

Um detalhe muito importante é que estamos falando de matriz aqui, *array* de *arrays* é outra coisa completamente diferente, ele pode ter tamanhos diferentes de linhas linhas e colunas, enquanto que a matriz precisa ser perfeitamente retangular. O *array* de *array* chama-se *jagged array*. [Veja exemplos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/148114/101).

Answer (score 0):

Para acessar o primeiro array usa `multiArray[0]`, o segundo usa `multiArray[1]` e assim usando indexação como se fosse um `array` de apenas uma dimensão.

Para acessar ao primeiro `index` dentro de cada `sub array` usa `multiArray[index][0]`.

**Aqui está um exemplo em Javascript que pode executar e ver o resultado:**

```js
 var multiArray = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]];

 console.log('Números no primeiro index do array multi dimensional')
 multiArray[0].forEach((value) => console.log(value));

 console.log('Números no primeiro index dos arrays dentro do array dimensional')
 multiArray.forEach((value) => console.log(value[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

É possível usar `foreach` se transformar o *array* em unidimensional, pegando só a primeira posição dos objetos:

```
string[,] operacoes = {
   { "SOMA", "x", "" },
   { "SUBTRAÇÃO", "x", "" },
   { "MULTIPLICAÇÃO", "x", "" },
   { "DIVISÃO", "x", "" }
};


var results = Enumerable
    .Range(0, operacoes.GetUpperBound(0) + 1)
    .Select(indice => operacoes[indice, 0])
    .ToArray();

foreach (var i in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Neste código usei o `Enumerable.Range` para gerar os índices para o tamanho do array, de zero até o tamanho (`operacoes.GetUpperBound(0) + 1`).

Depois, o `Select` seleciona a apenas o primeiro elemento de cada índice [0,0], [1,0], etc... usando o `indice`, que foram os índices gerados pelo `.Range`.

Finalmente, o `ToArray()` converte para array, para depois fazer o `foreach`

Aqui o código funcionando: [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7zKy3A)